# Does using a lone smite affect all missiles fired using Manyshot?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, paladin

Does a paladin with Ranged Smite and Manyshot add the damage bonus to all hits since it's only a single attack? And what about spells like *divine sacrifice* and *find the gap*?

Answer (score 1):

The paladin supernatural ability [**smite evil**](http://dndsrd.net/paladin.html#paladin-smite-evil), in part, says, "Once per day, a paladin may attempt to smite evil with one normal melee attack. She adds her Charisma bonus (if any) to her attack roll and deals 1 extra point of damage per paladin level" (*PH* 44). Thus, at its most basic, one use of the supernatural ability smite evil only ever modifies *one* attack's attack roll and damage roll.

Although the benefit of the feat [Manyshot](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#manyshot) (*Player's Handbook* 97) mandates that the creature use the same *attack roll* to determine whether or not each projectile hits and deals damage, multiple *attacks* are still being made. The effect of a smite—*both* its bonus on the attack roll *and* on the damage roll—applies only to one of those attacks.

(This means that despite Manyshot saying that its attacks "use the same attack roll," a paladin that, for example, uses the feats Manyshot and Ranged Smite (see below) to employ the supernatural ability smite evil at a distance with one projectile will be in the unusual position of having one projectile attack's result be different from her other projectile attacks' results!)

That the supernatural ability smite evil applies to just one attack holds true for the level 1 elf paladin racial substitution level supernatural ability **ranged smite evil** that says, in part, "An elf paladin can only deliver his smite evil attacks with a [bow]. The target must be within 30 feet for the paladin to use this ability. This ability otherwise functions identically to the normal smite evil class feature" of a typical paladin (*Races of the Wild* 155). This remains even more true for the exalted feat **Ranged Smite** that, in part, says, "Your smite evil ability can be channeled through *a missile* that you fire" (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 45 and emphasis mine).

The 1st-level paladin spell ***divine sacrifice*** [evoc] (*Spell Compendium* 70) affects only "[y]our first attack each round for the duration of the spell," even if your first *attack roll* is used to determine the outcome of multiple *attacks*. Likewise, the 3rd-level paladin spell ***find the gap*** [div] (*SpC* 91) says, "Your first melee or ranged attack each round is resolved as a touch attack," not caring that you made only one *attack roll* to determine if multiple attacks hit and deal damage.

However, since the supernatural ability evil can be used any number of times per round, that paladin could employ the benefit of the feat Manyshot and expend one smite evil attempt per missile to make during a standard action multiple ranged smite evil attempts.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm looking at it at a pure Rules as Written subject is following these corollaries:

- **I)** A Smite evil can be applied to any melee attack.
- **II)** The elven variant Ranged Smite from Races of the Wild allows a Paladin to apply his smite to a ranged attack made with a    bow.
- **III)** Manyshot is a feat that allows you to fire up to four arrows with a single attack roll.
- **IV)** You apply to the arrows fired by Manyshot any bonus to damage that is not precision damage (also detailed in many books    such as
  the rules compendium as Sneak attack, Skirmish and Sudden    strike
  unless otherwise noted on the damage entry)
- **V)** The spells Find the Gap and Divine Sacrifice apply to your first attack in the round.

So with those corollaries we have this situation:

Manyshot uses a single attack, wich is also the first attack you make in a round therefore applying find the gap and divine sacrifice in its rolls.
You can't declare to buff any single arrow from Manyshot because they are all fired at once, but you can buff the whole attack because of the simple roll.

On the oposing side @HeyIcanchan said that a smite evil can be applied to any simple attack, but a simple attack is not specified in the rules, if we consider that a simple attack is not any Special Attack then a simple attack is everything that is not a:
Aid another, Charge, Bullrush, Sunder, Grapple, Disarm, Overrun, Turn Undead or Two Weapon fighting
Wich are defined as special attacks under the rules, but the thing is you can use a Smite on a charge and while fighting with two weapons blurring even further what would be a special attack or otherwise noted as a "not a simple attack".

So Rules as Written the Smite, the effect from the Find the Gap spell and the bonus damage die from the Divine Sacrifice would apply to all arrows fired by the Manyshot.

Comment: So the question is *not* about the feat Ranged Smite (feats are upper case) but about the the class feature ranged smite evil (class features are lower case)? As rules-as-written questions require precision, I recommend updating the question to reflect this. Further, using this answer, could a creature during a Manyshot volley use one magic *+5 arrow* so that magic arrow's benefits applies to all the other (mundane) arrows launched during that volley?

Comment: @HeyICanChan From a Rules as Written point yes, since you only use a single attack roll any bonuses to those attack rolls would apply to all attacks, also there is the Magical Location Footsteps of Corellon from Dungeon Master's Guide II that gives the same benefit meaning that this is broader than just the class feature.

Comment: Also we have the Killoren Aspect of the Destroyer Smite that doesn't specify a melee attack, so I can be used with any attack and would also qualify.

Comment: (For a rules-as-written question, *everything* should be as specific as possible; each of these rules elements potentially has unique quirks that could lead to a different reading.) Huh. So using this answer, could a dude use Manyshot to launch both a *+1 keen arrow* and a mundane arrow on which has been cast *bless weapon* so that, if a critical hit is rolled, *all* arrows launched automatically confirm, despite the restrictions of the spell *bless weapon*?

Comment: Yes but only one stance of critical hit would apply due to the Special rulling of the Manyshot feat that describes that critical hits and precision damage is only applied once, the question for me is kinda specific already and my answer details everything in order to achieve my line of thought. I want to know if this is correct given no opposing corollaries have been presented.

Comment: Sincerely, I laud your consistency. Just to be clear, my answer (and the description of the paladin's smite evil) makes a distinction between *attack* and *attack roll*, yet this answer doesn't. Should this answer address that? (That is, not the smite description's *normal attack* part, but the part where it says *attack* first then,  later, by contrast, *attack roll*. Likewise, the  *footstep of Corellon* says *On a successful attack* not *On a successful attack **roll**.*)

Comment: I don't follow what are you trying to say, the attack is the action and the attack roll is the roll you make to undertake said action, so there isn't a bonus to attack, there is a bonus to an attack roll and what is succesful is the attack wich is the action you tried to accomplish.

Comment: The feat Manyshot allows the creature to make multiple attacks: "As a standard action, you may fire two arrows at a single opponent within 30 feet. Both arrows use the same attack roll (with a –4 penalty) to determine success and deal damage normally." While the same die result (the attack roll) is used to determine if each attack is a hit or a miss, the *modifiers* on those attacks may be different depending on special abilities (like smite evil) and ammunition (like a *+1 keen arrow*). I mean, "Damage reduction and other resistances apply separately against each arrow fired," after all.

Comment: I fail to find this statement as RAW because altough there is the caveat that the damage reduction and resistances apply at each instance it does not mention alterations in the attack roll applying to each arrow fired since it uses the same roll. The way you are describing it would be as if the bonus roll aplly to all arrows but the damage apply only once

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I follow exactly what @Victor said.
And my thinking about "why this case may treated like Spliting Weapon Enhancement" is just because the Occam's Razor way of thinking.

Like mentioned above, if during a Charge we can use smite, and Charge(PHB) is a full-round action and not a normal attack like wrote. But in Charging Smite(PHB2) we have: "

> *Beginning at 5th level, **if you smite evil on a charge attack**, you deal an extra 2 points of damage per paladin level to any evil
>   creature you hit (in addition to the normal bonus damage dealt by a
>   smite). If the charge attack misses, the smite ability is not
>   considered used. This is a supernatural ability."

- So, here we have the interpretation that Charge and Smite can be used together, even Charge(PHB) is considered Special Attack and not a Normal attack.

> "**Charging is a special full-round action** that allows you to move
>   up to twice your speed and attack during the action."

The "Volley rule" like mentioned(Rules Compendium, 42), is especific about precision-based damage.

> *"A number of abilities in the game allow a creature to deal extra damage by striking a vital area. This category of abilities includes
>   sneak attack and other abilities that work like it, such as a ninja’s
>   sudden strike (Complete Adventurer 8) and scout’s skirmish (Complete
>   Adventurer 12). For the sake of simplicity, the extra damage such
>   abilities deal is referred to as precision damage." [...]"**Precision
>   damage applies only against living creatures that have discernible
>   anatomies. Undead, constructs, deathless, oozes, plants, and
>   incorporeal creatures are not subject to precision damage, and
>   creatures that are not subject to critical hits are not subject to
>   precision damage."**[...]"A form of attack that enables an attacker to
>   make multiple attacks during an action other than a full-round action,
>   such as the Manyshot feat (standard action) or a quickened scorching
>   ray (swift action),allows precision damage to be applied only to the
>   first attack in the group."*

So far, we agree that ***Divine Sacrifice* and *Smite Evil* clear aren't "precision-based" damage** and normal attack that *Smite Evil* refers is a attack with a weapon.

Why not we go further and use *Smite Evil* on *Great Flyby Attack(SS)*? On my sight, by RAW, it's the "same situation", Smite Evil + Great Flyby Attack and Ranged Smite + Manyshot, because is just one attack roll in both circumstances.

> *Great Flyby Attack: "Using this feat is a full-round action. When flying, you can move up to your fly speed in a straight line and
>   attack a number of opponents equal to your Dexterity bonus. All
>   targets must be within your reach along the line of your movement.
>   **Make one attack roll, add the appropriate modifiers, and compare the result to the AC of each opponent you are attacking. If any hits are
>   successful, make one damage roll and add the appropriate modifiers.**
>   Each successful hit does the full damage to that creature; do not
>   divide the result of the damage roll among the targets. Targets of
>   your attack do not get attacks of opportunity against you, but other
>   opponents that would be entitled to attacks of opportunity may take
>   them."*

Here, if we use Great Flyby Attack + Smite Evil + Divine Sacrifice, we have just one attack roll as full-round action to hit multiple targets dealing the same damage to all.

> *Manyshot: As a standard action, you may fire two arrows at a single opponent within 30 feet. **Both arrows use the same attack roll (with
>   a -4 penalty) to determine success and deal damage normally** (but see
>   Special). For every five points of base attack bonus you have above
>   +6, you may add one additional arrow to this attack, to a maximum of four arrows at a base attack bonus of +16. However, each arrow after
>   the second adds a cumulative -2 penalty on the attack roll (for a
>   total penalty of -6 for three arrows and -8 for four). Damage
>   reduction and other resistances apply separately against each arrow
>   fired. Special Regardless of the number of arrows you fire, **you
>   apply precision-based damage (such as sneak attack damage) only
>   once.** If you score a critical hit, only the first arrow fired deals
>   critical damage; all others deal regular damage. A fighter may select
>   Manyshot as one of his fighter bonus feats (see page 38). A 6th-level
>   ranger who has chosen the archery combat style is treated as having
>   Manyshot even if he does not have the prerequisites for it, but only
>   when he is wearing light or no armor."

- *Manyshot feat* may be considered as Special Attack action, but we can use Manyshot + Smite Evil + Divine Sacrifice, the attack roll will be the same as Greater Flyby Attack, but damage need to be rolled for each arrow individual, applying Smite Evil damage and Divine Sacrifice Damage in each arrow separated, because, like I wrote above, it isn't precision-based damage.

In Spliting Weapon Enhancement(Champions of Ruin) says:

> *"Any missile fired from a splitting weapon, or an arrow or bolt enchanted with the splitting ability, breaks into two identical
>   missiles before striking the intended target. V-shaped engravings
>   adorn a splitting weapon or splitting ammunition. The splitting
>   ability of a ranged weapon (must be a bow, crossbow, arrow, or bolt)
>   only functions if its wielder has the Precise Shot feat. Any arrow or
>   bolt fired from a splitting weapon magically splits into two missiles
>   in mid-flight. **Both missiles are identical, sharing the nonsplitting
>   properties of the original missile; for example, a +1 splitting arrow
>   splits into two +1 arrows in mid-flight. Both missiles strike the same
>   target. Make a separate attack roll for each missile using the same
>   attack bonus.***"

So, here we don't have a sentence like *Manyshot* about precise-based damage, But therefore, in this case, "volley rule" apply in *Splitting Weapon Enhancement*, precise damage also counts on Spliting Weapon Enhancement, even in splitting you need to make one attack roll for each arrow, even explicit mentioned the splitted arrows share de same properties. That is, you shot one arrow with Sneak-Attack, if both hits, damage is dealt just one time for both arrow. However, like said above, **Divine Sacrifice and Smite Evil aren't Precision-based damage**, thus, in this scenario, damage from those apply individual for each arrow.

Is just a simple thing, using Occam's Razor proposition: If can't be applied, will be mentioned. If not mentioned, can be applied. So, based on reasoning above, **I can make this afirmation: The damage of Ranged Smite and Divine Sacrifice applies in each individual arrow using Manyshot Feat.**

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! There are several murky points here. First, Whirlwind Attack feat lets you make multiple attacks (one per opponent), so it is a bad example. Second, where is it stated you can smite evil on a charge? You can with an ACF, but without it it is highly questionable unless there is something in PHB that didn't get into SRD (like example of play or a sidebar). Even if you can, charge is quite different anyway. You can use special attack as part of a charge, but you can't split Manyshot to replase one of the attacks it offers. I think your answer would benefit from rules citations.

Comment: @annoyingimp There isn't a citation on the PHB that prevents you from using a smite evil on a charge, also the charging smite ACF describes that you get a damage bonus if you smite wich implies that you are already able to do so anyways. But I aggree that the Whirlwind attack example was bad.

Comment: @Victor First of all it implies you can smite without also charging. But generally it stumbles into the lack of a normal attack as a defined term again. So it depends on how you (or your DM) define it.

Comment: improved answer. Sorry for my newbe statement before. =D

Comment: Consider putting longer quotations in a quote box: start a new paragraph, type a `>`, then put the quotation after the `>`, adding another `>` at the beginning of the next paragraph if the quotation extends to multiple  paragraphs. It'll make the answer more appealing both visually and to read. (And no need to apologize. We're all new once! `:-)`)